# How to retrieve properties of a control say x,y,height,width,text etc in a WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm a beginner with limited knowledge in c#

[image]

How can we retrieve its coordinates and save it in a text file when the form is created?

Comment: of which part you need to know coordinates

Comment: if the form contains n controls , I need to retrieve all the controls x,y, height, width,and text to store it as seperate lines in a text file.

Comment: you need VisualTreeHelper, loop through each Visual Control and get its dimensions and position attributes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx,

Comment: Don't save them to a Text file... [save them to a user `.settings` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Persist application-scope property to isolated storage
        IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain();
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("abc.txt", FileMode.Create, storage))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            foreach (var keyValuePair in GetProperties(this))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("{0},{1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string,string> GetProperties(Window window)
    { 
        return new Dictionary<string,string>{
        {"Left",window.Left.ToString()},
        {"Top",window.Top.ToString()},
        {"Width",window.Width.ToString()},
        {"Height",window.Height.ToString()}
    };
    }
```